# completed. not the correct information

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to write a public method costMultiplier() that takes no arguments and returns a double. The method should return 1.2 for postcodes beginning “WC1A” or “EC1A”, and 1.0 otherwise.

```
public double costMultiplier()
return double
```

and now im stuck! many thanks

Comment: 1)  Where is this method expected to get the postcode from?  2) See [String.startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) for a way to proceed.

Comment: I have written a program.. this is just a part I am stuck on

Answer (score 1):

Your method would most likely look something like this:

```
public double costMultiplier(final String postCode) {
    double multiplier = 1.0d;  // Default

    // Trim off leading/trailing spaces and ensure Uppercase.
    String pc = postCode.trim().toUpperCase(); 

    if (pc.startsWith("WC1A") || pc.startsWith("EC1A")) {
        multiplier = 1.2;  // For London
    }

    return multiplier;
}
```

You would supply a specific postal code to this method, for example:

```
double multiplier = costMultiplier("EC1A 9DT");
System.out.println("Determined Multiplier = " + multiplier);
```

---

**EDIT: In response to OP's questions in comment:**

> Q: A) "Why should costMultiplier be public rather than private?"

If you want this method to be *used by other classes* in your project other than the class the method is contained in then declare the method as **public**. If you only want the method to be available to the class it is contained in then declare the method as **private**.

> Q: B) "Also I think for this part the string method substring() should
>   be used?"

Why would you think the **String#substring()** should be used? It is much easier to just use the **String#startsWith()** method and, we don't have to worry about invalid index values being supplied which can cause a **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**.

Actually either can be used however for simplicity it just makes better sense in certain circumstances to use the **String.startsWith()** method. The **String#startsWith()** method merely returns a boolean indicating whether or not the string supplied to the method is contained at the beginning of the string (or string variable) it is played against:

```
String postCode = "EC1A 9DT";
System.out.println(postCode.startsWith("EC1A"));
// Prints true in console.
```

whereas the **String#substring()** method returns a slice from the String (or string variable) the method is played against based on a offset and a count value. In order to get a boolean you then need to compare that slice against the string you want to confirm exists at the same offset and count:

```
String postCode = "EC1A 9DT";
System.out.println(postCode.substring(0, 4).equals("EC1A"));
// Prints true in console.
```

if however:

```
String postCode = ""; // OR postCode = "EC1"
System.out.println(postCode.substring(0, 4).equals("EC1A"));
// A StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown!
```

whereas if:

```
String postCode = ""; // OR postCode = "EC1"
System.out.println(postCode.startsWith("EC1A"));
// Prints false in console.
```

In my opinion, when using the String#substring() method you should utilize a mechanism to ensure that that the string you plan to slice is large enough to handle the Offset and Count you pass to the method especially when you have no clue or guarantee of what that string might contain:

```
String postCode = "e3e";  // String is too short.
boolean trueFalse = false;
if (postCode.length() > 3) {
    trueFalse = postCode.substring(0, 4).equals("EC1A");
}
System.out.println(trueFalse);
// Prints false in console.
```

It's a matter of preference. You decide which you want to use, **String#startsWith()** or **String#substring()**.

Comment: thank you for your help. Why should costMultiplier be public rather than private? also i think for this part the string method substring() should be used?

Comment: @Samidillo - See **Edit** in the post above with regards to your other questions.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your help :)